# Declaring local variable to the main function

Tags: c, function, scope, cs50

So I'm doing the [CS50 Readability problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/) set using C and I'm a little bit confused about how to use the local variables of other functions in the `main` function.

Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int count(string text);
int grading(float index);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    count(text);

    float index = 0.0588 * (100*((float)letter/(float)word)) - 0.296 * (100*((float)sentence/(float)word)) - 15.8;

    grading(index);
}

int count(string text)
{
    int letter = 0;
    int word = 1;
    int sentence = 0;

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'z'){
            letter += 1;
        }
    
        else if(text[i] == ' '){
            word += 1;
        }
    
        else if(text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '.'){
            sentence += 1;
         }
    }

    printf("%i letters\n", letter);
    printf("%i words\n", word);
    printf("%i sentences\n", sentence);
}


int grading(float index)
{
    if (index >= 16) {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else if (index < 1) {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Grade %f\n", round(index));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I use `letter`, `word` and `sentence` in `main` after calling `count`?

Comment: `Anyone can help me?` Help with what exactly? [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: FWIW, `if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'z')` is wrong, there are a bunch of characters after `Z` and before `a` that are not letters.

Comment: `float index = 0.0588 * (100*((flo....` All those variables only exist in `count` so maybe that calculation should go there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OHH thanks, yea I'm a little bit new with programming, it really helps! solved it already :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use local variables defined in a function in another function. If you want to keep the values calculated in `count`, you will have to return them somehow.

Since you are calculating three different values, but a function can only return one value, I would suggest to create an helper `struct` to return:

```c
struct result {
    unsigned letters;
    unsigned words;
    unsigned sentences;
};
```

Then, in `count` you can do this:

```c
struct result count(string text)
{
    struct result res = {.letters = 0, .words = 0, .sentences = 0};

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') || (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')){
            res.letters += 1;
        }
    
        else if (text[i] == ' '){
            res.words += 1;
        }
    
        else if (text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '.'){
            res.sentences += 1;
         }
    }

    printf("%i letters\n", res.letters);
    printf("%i words\n", res.words);
    printf("%i sentences\n", res.sentences);

    return res;
}
```

And finally in `main`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    struct result res = count(text);

    float index = 0.0588 * (100*((float)res.letters/(float)res.words)) - 0.296 * (100*((float)res.sentences/(float)res.words)) - 15.8;

    grading(index);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can just calculate the result in the `count` function itself:

```c
float count(string text)
{
    int letter = 0;
    int word = 1;
    int sentence = 0;

    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'z'){
            letter += 1;
        }
    
        else if(text[i] == ' '){
            word += 1;
        }
    
        else if(text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '.'){
            sentence += 1;
         }
    }

    printf("%i letters\n", letter);
    printf("%i words\n", word);
    printf("%i sentences\n", sentence);

    return 0.0588 * (100*((float)letter/(float)word)) - 0.296 * (100*((float)sentence/(float)word)) - 15.8;
}
```

Then in `main`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    float index = count(text);
    grading(index);
}
```

Comment: Another option is to pass three pointers to separate counts to the analytic function, and have the analytic function assign to those pointers.  The calling code can then do as it needs with the numbers.  Separating the counting from the calculations and printing is probably a good idea.